# Issue with adding suite name in gulp protractor

Tags: protractor, gulp-protractor

I am stuck with Gulp as a wrapper. I have multiple spec files in my work for different projects(websites) and i want to create test suites out of these spec files.
Below is the code written by someone in gulp
 `

```
var binPath = './node_modules/.bin/';

gulp.task('test-all', function(cb) {
  async.eachSeries(glob.sync('sites/*'), testSite, cb);
});
gulp.task('test', function(cb) {
  env.validate(util.env, {
    site: {
      required: true,
    },
    useSelenium: {
      required: false,
    },
    params: {
      required: false,
    }
  });
  testSite('sites/' + util.env.site, cb);
});

gulp.task('explorer', function(cb) {
  runProtractor(['--elementExplorer', '--directConnect'], cb);
});

gulp.task('serve', function(cb) {
  runModule('webdriver-manager', ['start'], cb);
});
gulp.task('update', function(cb) {
  runModule('webdriver-manager', ['update'], cb);
});
gulp.task('default', ['test']);
function runModule(name, params, cb) {
  new simpleCommand(path.join(binPath, name), params, process.cwd()).run(cb);
}
function runProtractor(params, cb) {
  runModule('protractor', params, cb);
}
function testSite(site, cb) {
  var params = [
    site + '/protractor.conf.js', suite=smoke,
    '--params.timestamp=' + timestamp
  ];
  if (!util.env.useSelenium) {
    params.push('--directConnect');
  }
  if (util.env.params) {
    params.push(util.env.params.replace(/(^['"]|['"]$)/g, '').trim());
  }
  util.log('Testing ' + site);
  runProtractor(params, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      util.log(err);
    }
    cb();
  });
}
```

`
I have now specified suite name which i want to execute above. But i want to capture this name of suite from command line argument.

```
gulp test --site [sitename] --suite=smoke
```

How will i be able to capture suite name from above statement?

Comment: I tried gulp test --site sitename --params "--suite='smoke'" but it is giving me an error "TypeError: util.env.params.replace is not a function

Comment: I know where i need to edit in my gulp.js file. My question is if i specify command gulp test --site sitename --suite='smoke'. how should i be able to capture --suite=smoke which i entered in CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work.

```
function testSite(site, cb) {
  var params = [
    site + '/protractor.conf.js', '--suite='+util.env.suite,
    '--params.timestamp=' + timestamp
```